# LINQ query structure with if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity

I have a full LINQ query built out.  I need one query run if the user is a manager/team lead and a separate query run if they are not.  However the queries are very similar.

Manager/Teamleads get to see everything.  Where as others only see what they are certified for.

```
var model = (from d in department
                join f in db.IPACS_Function on d.departmentID equals f.departmentID
                join pg in db.IPACS_Process on f.functionID equals pg.functionID
                join sop in db.IPACS_Procedure on pg.processID equals sop.processID
                // Non-Manager/Teamlead portion
                join cert in db.IPACS_Certification on sop.procedureID equals cert.procedureID
                join procdoc in db.IPACS_ProcedureDocs on sop.procedureID equals procdoc.procedureID
                join doc in db.IPACS_Document on procdoc.documentID equals doc.documentID
                where cert.adUserName == currUser && cert.certifiedDate > doc.dateApproved
                // End non-manager/team lead
                select new IPACS_DT_MasterList
                {
                    departmentID = d.departmentID,
                    functionID = f.functionID,
                    processID = pg.processID,
                    procedureID = sop.procedureID,
                    departmentName = d.name,
                    functionName = f.name,
                    processName = pg.name,
                    procedureName = sop.name,
                    owner = sop.owner,
                    automated = (bool)sop.automated
                });
```

Is what I am trying to do above possible without creating two separate `var model =` statements?

Comment: What is your LINQ provider? In LINQ to Objects an if statement is certainly not a problem. I would imagine LINQ to SQL would generate the appropriate case statement however I'm not sure that's the case.

Comment: Why would you write code that, from what I can see, would be deliberately less readable and maintainable?

Comment: @AdrianWragg I generally agree however his data source requires 6 joins so it's not like it will be more readable in some other format. If you could change the SQL schema that would be the preferred solution but that's rarely an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just create a query, and then if not a teamleader add the additional join/where clauses before the query is sent to the data source

ie:

```
var query = (from d in department
            join f in db.IPACS_Function on d.departmentID equals f.departmentID
            join pg in db.IPACS_Process on f.functionID equals pg.functionID
            join sop in db.IPACS_Procedure on pg.processID equals sop.processID

            select new {d, f, pg, sop});



if (!TeamLeader){
        query = from x in query
            // Non-Manager/Teamlead portion
            join cert in db.IPACS_Certification on x.sop.procedureID equals cert.procedureID
            join procdoc in db.IPACS_ProcedureDocs on x.sop.procedureID equals procdoc.procedureID
            join doc in db.IPACS_Document on procdoc.documentID equals doc.documentID
            where cert.adUserName == currUser && cert.certifiedDate > doc.dateApproved
            // End non-manager/team lead
            select x;
}

var model = (from x in query
            select new IPACS_DT_MasterList
            {
                departmentID = x.d.departmentID,
                functionID = x.f.functionID,
                processID = x.pg.processID,
                procedureID = x.sop.procedureID,
                departmentName = x.d.name,
                functionName = x.f.name,
                processName = x.pg.name,
                procedureName = x.sop.name,
                owner = x.sop.owner,
                automated = (bool)x.sop.automated
            });
```